# Convolution with an even function

Tags: analysis, convolution

I apologise upfront for the dumb question, but I just totally got stuck with this.

An apparent contradiction when taking the convolution with an even function.

For two (nice) functions $f$ and $g$ consider
$$
(f*g)(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x-y)g(y) dy.
$$

Assume $f$ to be even (i.e., $f(-x)=f(x)$ for all $x$). Pedantically enough, define
$$
f_1(x):=f(x),\qquad f_2(x):=f(-x).
$$
Clearly, $f_1\equiv f_2$.

Now, 
$$
\begin{split}
 &\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x-y)g(y) dy \\
 &= (f*g)(x) = (f_1*g)(x) = (f_2*g)(x) \\
 &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(-x-y)g(y) \\
 &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x+y)g(y) dy.
\end{split}
$$

Except that the identity
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x-y)g(y) dy = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x+y)g(y) dy
$$
is false in general. For instance, with $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ and $g(x)= \sqrt{\frac{8}{\pi}}x e^{-x^2}$ one has
$$
\begin{split}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x-y)g(y) dy = x e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} \\
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x+y)g(y) dy = -x e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}.
\end{split}
$$

So what went wrong.....?

Comment: $f_2(x-y) = f(y-x)$, which generally is different from $f(-x-y)$.

Comment: You're right, of course, thanks. So is there a way to interpret $\int f(x+y)g(y)dy$ as a convolution $(h*g)(x)$ for some $h$?

Comment: I don't see that, but of course $\int f(x+y)g(y)\,dy = (\check{f} \ast g)(-x) = (f \ast \check{g})(x)$, where $\check{\varphi}(u) = \varphi(-u)$. Maybe that works too for you.